# How to print set of PDF files (say 3 files) from simple java application by using just java API

Tags: java, pdf, printing, awt

I'm stuck with a task which is related to printing the PDF file from java application.

Let me explain the question once again in little in detailed:
How to print set of PDF files (say 3 files) from simple java application by using just java API i.e. without using any third party tool and without opening the PDF files?

Info that might be useful is, My printer supports these formats:

```
    image/gif; class="[B"
image/gif; class="java.io.InputStream"
image/gif; class="java.net.URL"
image/jpeg; class="[B"
image/jpeg; class="java.io.InputStream"
image/jpeg; class="java.net.URL"
image/png; class="[B"
image/png; class="java.io.InputStream"
image/png; class="java.net.URL"
application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class="java.awt.print.Pageable"
application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class="java.awt.print.Printable"
application/octet-stream; class="[B"
application/octet-stream; class="java.net.URL"
application/octet-stream; class="java.io.InputStream"
```

I'm interested in the code that does the work of sending the print job of printing PDF files directly to the printer (at the background).

NOTE: Printing should be done at the background. I/My application should not wait for the print job to be completed. What I mean to say is my application should work asynchronously irrespective of the printing job is completed or not?

Comment: *"How to print set of PDF files (say 3 files) from simple java application by using just java API i.e. without using any third party tool and without opening the PDF files?"*  ..Magic?  I would have suggested `Desktop.print()` but that does not fulfill 'in the background'.  All this BTW, is a great way to dump 250+ pages of 'coupons for adult products & services' to the company high-speed printer..

Comment: Hi Andrew, I tried Desktop.print() already. By the way, I came to know of that Desktop.print() after doing long search, but still I'm not done with the complete task. Anyhow your answer helps to achieve the task. I appreciate your time. Thanks for your help. But still I need the way to do it all at a once in the background. Its a web service code which prints set of pdf byte arrays to the printer at the back. Thats the idea.

Comment: For that situation, I would look to add a PDF API that can talk directly to printer.  Why 'no 3rd party API'?

Comment: Because It'll take long time to get approval in my company since there is a legal process to follow. It may take almost for 3 months.

Comment: It might to 4+ months to come up with your own 'core Java' implementation..

Comment: Thats the reason I approached Stackoverflow so that I can get some way/idea to finish it of quickly by some means :).